# Adding a home button to web view

Tags: ios, webview

In my storyboard app I have a web view which displays a website. When I run the app, everything looks good, and I can view the website fine, but if I go to other pages within the website, then I go to another part of the app, when I return to the web view it is at the same place I left off in the website. The only way for me to display the home page of the website is to quit the app and restart.

Is it possible to add a home button to the web view somehow that will allow the user to make the website within the app go to the home page of the website?

Comment: Sure. All you have to do is create an IBOutlet property for your webView that loads a url (your home url) from an IBAction (your button). Fundamentals I suppose. If you need a working example let me know

Comment: Add navigation bar button to load first page in UIWebView

Comment:  that works too. This is probably a duplicate question I'm sure. Have you searched SO for reference?

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort it out, I now have the necessary home link on the website pages so my issue is resolved